# Linearizing constraint ( multiplication of binary variables)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, linearization, binary-programming

I am trying to think of contraint(s) that can linearize constraint below.

$\sum_{T} \sum_{TR} Z_{(T,D)}* Y_{(TR,T)}  \leq CAP_{(D)} \forall D$

Both Z nad Y are Binary Variables and CAP is capacity parameter.

I tried to apply big M but without luck.

Comment: you need to linearize each product, so you get $\sum_ t \sum_{tr} x_{t,d,rt} \leq cap(d)$

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do it without introducing third variables with three indices to keep the complexity of the algorithm minimal, so do you mean I need a third variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Although the [usual linearization of a product of two binary variables](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables/473#473) requires three inequalities, you can get by with only one here.  You can enforce
$(Z \land Y) \implies X$ via linear constraint $Z + Y - 1 \le X$.

Comment: I don't understand how this works, I will try to give some context, Z gives value of 1 if truck t is used for distribution centre d and y gives value of 1 if trip t is utilized for truck t , i want to give capacity constraint thus :
40* $\sum_{T} \sum_{TR} Z_{(T,D)}* Y_{(TR,T)}  \leq CAP_{(D)} \forall D$

Comment: I think I Got you , I need to introduce third binary variable X and use it in the original constraint right?

Comment: Yes, like in @LinAlg's comment.